# Managing songs on Ipod Shuffle

Tags: 14.04

I'm Pretty new to Ubuntu and i've had no success in installing Itunes through Wine, So i'm wondering if there is anyother software that can help me manage my songs on my ipod.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rythmbox to transfer music.

Just place the music you want to add in the `~/music` folder and open rythmbox.

connect your iPod.

Drag the music from the computer to your iPod.

This method worked for my old iPod nano 3rd generation but it should work for you too.

rythmbox is usually installed in ubuntu by default so you don't have to install anything new either.